# Optionally optional default function arguments depending on template arguments

Tags: c++

I got asked the following question by a student: can a function's argument be optional depending on a template argument ?

That is, given:

```cpp
struct Car{};
struct Plane{};

struct OptionCar{};
struct OptionPlane1{};
struct OptionPlane2{};

template <typename T, typename U>
void foo(const T& a, const T& b, U option /* = ??? */) ;
```

One should be able to call for Car with a default argument:

```
Car c;
foo(c, c); // invokes foo(const Car&, const Car&, OptionCar);
```

but not for Plane:

```
Plane p;
foo(p, p); // compile error
foo(p, p, OptionPlane1{}); // ok
foo(p, p, OptionPlane2{}); // ok
```

Comment: You can achieve this by using overloads instead of default argument parameters. Is this feasible?

Comment: not in this case, the function should really not be duplicated as far as possible

Comment: you don't need to duplicate it. Both overloads can call the same function

Comment: the function prototypes would be duplicated. it counts as code, too !

Comment: if you count that as code duplication I am not sure if there is any solution that isnt

Comment: well the one I posted is less duplicat-ey, although I'd like to type { { Car, OptionCar }, ... } instead of `mp::mp_list<...` which gives me wrist pain by the mere thought of it

Comment: frankly it looks like you know solutions but you don't want them. If idiomatic solutions are excluded all you are left with is something hacky and I don't understand what else you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

The current solution I have is:

```cpp
template<typename T, typename U = std::conditional_t<std::is_same_v<Car, T>, OptionCar, void>>
void foo(const T& a, const T& b, U option = {});
```

But it feels a bit like a hack. Curious about anything better.

Edit: another solution, which looks a bit cleaner and more extensible, with boost:

```cpp
#include <boost/mp11.hpp>

struct Car{};
struct Plane{};
struct Bus{};

struct OptionCar{};
struct OptionPlane{};
struct OptionBus1{};
struct OptionBus2{};

namespace mp = boost::mp11;

using OptionTypeMap = 
  mp::mp_list<
    mp::mp_list<Car, OptionCar>,
    mp::mp_list<Plane, OptionPlane>
>;

template <typename T, typename U = mp::mp_second<mp::mp_map_find<OptionTypeMap, T>>>
void foo(T const& a, T const& b , U option = {}) 
{

}

int main()
{
  // ok:
  foo(Car{}, Car{});
  foo(Plane{}, Plane{});
  foo(Bus{}, Bus{}, OptionBus1{});

  // not ok:
  // foo(Bus{}, Bus{});
}
```

Comment: why does it feel like a hack? Afaik SFINAE originated as a hack, but with concepts in C++20 the same can be done in a much less hacky fashion

Comment: well, yes, SFINAE is a hack, that's why. concepts here would not remove the "hackish" part of it, which is having to make a variable of type void in some cases and not in others